# Minimal polynomial requirements

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I'm a bit confused with how we can show a given polynomial that annihilates a linear transformation $T$ is a minimal polynomial.

In one particular problem, I have the polynomial $x^m - 1$ annihilates a transformation $T$. I know that this polynomial has $m$ distinct roots, and imagine that this "distinct" gives me that the polynomial must be minimal, but am not sure if that's enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if $T$ is the identity transformation, say?

Comment: Then the polynomial is x-1 which has one root (1), and it is the minimal polynomial I believe. Isn't it?

Comment: You wrote $x^m-1$ with no other information about $m$. If you take $m=2$ and $T$ the identity, do you see an issue?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In this case, m is the exponent such that T^m is the identity. Should T be the identity, m = 1 necessarily.

Comment: Note "the exponent such that $T^m$ is the identity" is not well-defined because there could be more than one such $m$, as that example illustrates. Your assumptions are not clear. If you are working on a particular problem it would be best to post that problem together with all relevant assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no criterion on the polynomial only (such as having simple roots) that can tell you whether a given annihilating polynomial is minimal for $T$; it depends on $T$. (However, if a polynomial fails to be monic, it is certainly not a minimal polynomial.) It is well known that any monic polynomial is the minimal polynomial of (multiplication by) its own companion matrix, so any such polynomial *could* be the minimal polynomial. If an annihilating monic polynomial is irreducible over the field considered (and one is in non-zero dimension so that $1$ is not an annihilating polynomial) it has to be the minimal polynomial because only its monic divisors are candidates.